# Single Line of Text field not working in IE11

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, ie-11

I've got a SP2013 list with a Single Line of Text field that isn't accepting any input from the keyboard. The other fields work fine, and I can select the single line of text field, but nothing appears when I type. This only happens in IE11, but the field works in Chrome. I'm not sure what's happening, as this worked fine last week, and there haven't been any changes since then that I'm aware of.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: Is it an OOTB field or is it customized (JSlink / farm solution / etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a local problem with your IE11.
Try reopen browser and  turn on debugger console. Are there any js mistakes in console ?

Comment: I don't think it's local, it's happening on quite a few different computers. I opened the debugger and didn't see anything obvious, but I'm not the Sharepoint dev, so I'll wait until he gets back so he can take an educated look